# googledrive Move File Script just began failing and wont work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

The following code used to run on a Trigger every 4 mins. This would move all files (Not Folders) from the Root of my Google Drive the the specified directory.
This began to fail and no longer works. It errors on Line 6 `destination.addFile(file);`
with the following error `Exception: Invalid argument (line 6, file "Code")`

```
function MoveFiles(){
var files = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1k7UaP_5oBoHdS6OIbyaPT0M0DM2uUq78");
    destination.addFile(file);
    var pull = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    pull.removeFile(file);   
  }
}
```

Can anyone see why this would occur?

Comment: Are you always using the same folder as destination or is it a new one? Is it a folder on your drive or on a shared drive?

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
function MoveFiles(){
  const root=DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  const files=root.getFiles();
  const destination=DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    destination.addFile(file);
    root.removeFile(file);   
  }
}
```

I tested it with a trigger and it works